# ENV variable within an ENV variable in upstart script

Tags: 14.04, bash, upstart

I'm trying to include one ENV var in another in my upstart script:

```
env CONFIG_NODE_NAME=my_$HOSTNAME_node
```

But it doesn't translate it, it just keeps it as `$HOSTNAME`.

Answer (score 1):

Add braces around the variable. I assume you are trying to use the `$HOSTNAME` environment variable.

```
env CONFIG_NODE_NAME=my_${HOSTNAME}_node
```

Comment: This kind of works, I can see that it tries to translate the `${HOSTNAME}`, however the service reports that it cannot resolve it, which is weird.

Comment: Strange, maybe this variable isnt set at the time. You could try to invoke the hostname binary instead. The command would look like this `env CONFIG_NODE_NAME=my_$(hostname)_node`

Comment: It's weird since I'm running this service manually long after boot. So HOSTNAME should definitely be available. I can also see the correct result of I just echo `$HOSTNAME` in my bash console. Using `$(hostname)` doesn't work, the upstart script fails to run.

Comment: It's probably not using the bash interpreter: http://superuser.com/questions/132489/hostname-environment-variable-on-linux. What error do you get when using `$(hostname) `? Did you try `$(/bin/hostname)`